# Problem with add_rewrite_rule and pagination (paged and page query_vars)

Tags: url-rewriting, pagination, rewrite-rules

I have a custom taxonomy named `location` and I want to add sections like 'news' and 'marketplace' for each term, so my url looks like `/location/montreal/news/`

It works perfectly until I try to add pagination. Here is my code :

```
add_action( 'init', 'region_rewrite' );
function region_rewrite()
{
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var( 'section' );

    add_rewrite_rule(
      '^location/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)/?',
      'index.php?location=$matches[1]&section=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]',
      'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
      '^location/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
      'index.php?location=$matches[1]&section=$matches[2]',
      'top'
    );
}
```

I'm using the [Rewrite analyser plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) and it seems that the query_vars location, section and paged are assigned with the right value. However, I get a 404 error when trying to access a page url like `/location/montreal/news/page/2`. I also noticed that the the `page` variable has the value `/2`. Is it possible that this is why I'm getting a 404 not found ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I find that when going to deep into pretty permalinks (too many variables) that working out the rewrite rules overwhelms me. I tend to just append an old ugly query to the end and call it a day.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could just call the paged `add_rewrite_url` **last** so that it is checked first. Otherwise the paged version will never get any match, since the non-paged one will always match first. Should also  work if you remove 'top' from your arguments.

Also, check out this page for a nice way of debugging those 404 when working with custom rewrite:
http://www.dev4press.com/2012/tutorials/wordpress/practical/debug-wordpress-rewrite-rules-matching/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Olivier. My own issue was that my add_rewrite_url was working fine for pages but not all posts.

It worked for posts if using only `%postname%/` in permalink setup.
I kept losing the bit after the post url if using `/%category%/%postname%/`
i.e. `http://me.com/test/post/my-next-bit-that-url-rewrite-should-act-on`
kept 301 redirecting to `http://me.com/test/post/my-next-bit-that-url-rewrite-should-act-on`
because of the canonical behaviour of wordpress

The line below stopped this issue.

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

I reckon it should be suggested in the codex.

Comment: Removing [`redirect_canonical` removes important functionality](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/canonical.php#L13). I would suggest removing it only with extreme caution and as a last resort.